# Future predator, could it happen in any way?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution, alternate-reality

The show [Primeval](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808096/) introduced us to many interesting concepts and creatures (some fictional and others not quite), but maybe its most memorable one might be the [future predator](https://primeval.fandom.com/wiki/Future_Predator), a creature that, as the name suggests, would evolve in a future in which we went extinct to become an apex or superpredator. In the show it's stated that they'd evolved from bats, likely due to their use of echolocation, however this didn't seem right, given their size and few similarities with bats other than that.

[image]

Now, so you don't need to go to the wiki, here are the main traits of the creature:

- is 2.5 meters tall.
- walks on it's knuckles (see picture).
- has 2 fingers on its forelimbs with strong claws that can dig into flesh and slice metal to some extent.
- impressive speed and cooling capabilities, being able to run at speeds above 110km/h for relatively prolonged periods.
- relies on speed and agility rather than strength to hunt, but has been shown able to easily kill an adult male lion.
- has a human-sized brain with comparable intellect, capable of problem solving and fast learning (disarmed armed men after previously being shot by one); it's not sapient however.
- lacks eyes, relying on a echolocation through a [melon organ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melon_(cetacean)) and fused ears on the center of its head to hunt and locate itself.
- hearing is sensitive enough to pick a human heartbeat.
- is a skilled climber, able to scale walls and leap very long distances (around 20 meters away from ground point 0)
- durable akin to or greater than a grizzly bear, and able to shake off machine gun rounds with relative ease, but having an apparently weaker skull, with a single low caliber bullet being enough to pierce it.
- has rough greyish skin, visually similar to an elephant's.

Given these traits, what creature from our planet could actually evolve into such beasts? Could all of these these traits exist simultaneously on a creature? I have a feeling this animal had exaggerated traits to make it overpowered and maximize its "cool factor", as cheetahs for example can only run at around 100 km/h for very short periods before risking overheating themselves.

I'll add that this animal apparently evolved to inhabit the remains of large cities, and the atmospheric conditions of this time seem to be extremely rich in oxygen, perhaps with the atmosphere becoming slightly denser as well, given they live alongside insects as large as [arthropleura](http://www.prehistoric-wildlife.com/species/a/arthropleura.html), capable of limited flight.

Note/edit: The purpose of this question is to explore the overlapping traits of this creature and whether it could actually evolve on an earth like planet. Although it exists in a universe of its own (meaning this could be accidentally seen as a Sci-fi stack exchange question), I'm interested in its qualities, as many of them are similar to those of a nocturnal creature in my own story, so I'm interested if it could actually evolve naturally, if at all; and possibly what kinds of pressure would lead to its evolution.

Comment: Seems like somebody else already built this world, so I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "explore certain traits?" Lots of things are *possible* but not *probable*, and some traits can be simultaneously cool and very silly.

Comment: `echolocation` and `fused ears on the center of its head` - the second may improve the sensibility to low level of sounds but will blow the capability of location into the impossible territory. You may want to consider how the [sound localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization) work (no matter the sound trait that's used for discrimination, it still needs at least two ears. More than one will improve the precision but likely require more processing power or be slower)

Comment: This creature has no special or extraordinary abilities or characteristics that are not possessed by some existing animal so the only possible answer is "Yes, given enough time of course it's possible" or some variation thereof so why are you even asking? I can only assume in writing all this detail you've forgotten to ask the question you really want answered?

Comment: @Pelinore thanks for the criticism, I tried editing my question to make it clearer and more focused, as well as explaining why such a question is not in the sci-fi stack exchange.

Comment: `cooling capabilities, run at speeds above 100km/h for prolonged periods` Doesn't seem likely - that muscular mass will require higher cooling surface or withstanding higher body temperatures for long period of times.

Comment: Aha! so your real question / area of interest is 'what environmental, competitive & evolutionary pressures might plausibly lead to this evolutionary end-product?' which is an interesting one but falls afoul of too broad & opinion based, nearest thing to a question of that ilk that fits the sites rules is for you to provide your idea on what brings it about & ask 'is this plausible' ~ some of your given stats seem at odds with those I found here [***They are extremely agile, but this comes at a cost, as they are easily stunned***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_creatures_in_Primeval)?

Comment: @Pelinore not quite, I'm looking for whether such a creature could evolve this group of traits naturally, if at all, which would fall more under the "yes or no" category. And regarding the easily stunned, scrambling their sonar will leave them helpless, which would be expected when it relies so much on sound. As for why I didn't just present my creature, it sounded more effective to question about this one, as it shares many traits while having others I'm also interested in but don't fit my beast. I could simply erase the name if you think it'd benefit the overall question.

Comment: Nah, let it ride & see what others think, I'm just one & not voting to close (now).

Comment: @Pelinore thank you, I am aware of the risks of this being seen as off topic , and tried to explain in the edit why I'm asking about a creature that is not my own creation, especially when I see so many movie Monsters which seem to have been inspired by it, leaving me to think more people would like to know whether these traits could overlap in a creature for their own creations.

Comment: Yep, after my initial knee jerk response (a bit too stroppy & judgemental, think I need sleep) I'm standing completely aside to see what longer serving souls response is ;)

Comment: `a knuckle walker` and `impressive speed...  above 110km/h` are sorta incompatible. Knuckle walker suggest a mass concentrated in the upper part of the body with the lower limbs unable to provide balance by themselves, but then the upper limbs aren't used for propulsion. Which raise the question ... how does the creature balances itself during 110km/h runs and how can one be agile with a balance impairment?

Comment: Sorry, edits cannot invalidate existing answers. I have rolled the edit back.

Comment: @L.Dutch -  Reinstate Monica It's ok, I'd honestly delete this question if I could, as it was clearly a mistake. Quick question: how do I ask a question for the anatomically correct series? Do I simply add the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your creature seems mixing incompatible traits, namely

> being able to reach max speeds above 100km/h

together with

> relies on speed and agility rather than strength to hunt

do not go well with

> being able to shake off machine gun rounds with relative ease

The only land animal capable of reaching those speeds is the [cheetah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheetah), which has a very slender body figure. This in order to reduce weight and allow sprinting to those very speeds.

All of this seems clashing with the stocky body required to shake off bullets. Also the impression that the body gives is not that of an elite runner. See also the body of sight-hounds: specialized in velocity, they are not bulky.

Comment: Maybe an ambush predator? I.e. can develop a reaction speed in excess of 100km/h in one burst, linear trajectory, hit-or-miss; then requires long time to recharge. But then it contradicts 'agility'.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, that's exactly the cheetah. They can't afford many failed attempts, else they deplete their reserves

Comment: Yeah, naah. Was taking the entire context of "bullet proof body" + "high speed *and agile*". One may imagine "bullet proof + high speed" but it won't be agile - bullet proofing will require additional tissue mass to disperse the momentum/energy of a bullet, additional mass comes with additional inertia, latter being at odds with agility. This even letting aside the "speeds above 110km/h *for relatively prolonged periods*".

Comment: I think the comments on their hardiness is perhaps misplaced? descriptions I find don't give a top speed but do say they are fast & agile, possibly a misplaced assumption on some scene or other watched, being shot at doesn't mean they were hit & body shots are often not immediately fatal & can miss any vital organs anyway, while a head shot rarely misses the relative vital organ.